# git bash pwd command gives incorrect case for drive

Tags: windows, bash

On git bash when I run the pwd command this gives me an output of the current drive (C in this case) in lower case. However, if I check the current directory on cmd it gives it to me in upper case.

I am not bothered by the slashes in the opposite direction, I just want to know why git bash is converting my c drive to lower case.

**Git bash**

[image]

**cmd**

[image]

Comment: bash being POSIX obviously doesn't know the Windows namespace

Comment: is there a way to fix this?

Comment: no, if you use POSIX tools then learn POSIX rules. For example `$PATH` in POSIX is separated by `:` so how can it work with Windows `%PATH%` which uses `:` for the drive letter and `;` to separate? Running Windows tools in bash will never work if it can't find files in the path

Comment: @rishi : Drive letters on Windows are not case sensitive, i.e. you can not have `e:` and `E:` as different drives. Therefore any application is free to choose how to display the letter. When I type the drive letter on the command line, I nearly always use lower case. This spares me from having to use the shift key.

Comment: @phuclv : This depends on the bash implementation: For instance, if you use Cygwin, the colon works fine, even in PATH. I have in my PATH a part looking like `/bin:c:/wbin:$HOME/bin` and the colon after the `c` is not interpretaed as separator. `git bash` and the bash coming with WSL is different in this respect.

Comment: @user1934428 obviously, otherwise how can bash work? The PATH environment variable is automatically converted in cygwin and MSYS2. As I said, in a POSIX environment like cygwin or MSYS the rules must follow the POSIX rules and you can't use Windows path in POSIX. Even wsl and wsl2 have their own paths and you can't use Windows path in them

Comment: @phulcv : Partially true: Of course you can not use a Windows part in the original form, simply because Windows uses backslashes as separators. At least with Cygwin, you can use what is termed in Cygwin-speech as "mixed" denotation for a directory, which means that you have a drive letter and a colon, but forward slashes; and this is something which **can** be a component of the `PATH` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why git bash is converting my c drive to lower case

the git bash is not converting anything here, it's about how your drives are mounted.
just check the output of `mount` and you should see something like

```
C: on /c type ntfs
```

which is the origin of the lowercase c